# What is Proof of Stake (PoS)?

Tags: mining, proof-of-stake

What is the Proof of Stake and how this concept is (or will be) related with Ethereum?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof-of-stake):

> Proof-of-stake (PoS) is a method by which a cryptocurrency blockchain
>   network aims to achieve distributed consensus. While the proof-of-work
>   (PoW) method asks users to repeatedly run hashing algorithms or other
>   client puzzles, to validate electronic transactions, proof-of-stake
>   asks users to prove ownership of a certain amount of currency (their
>   "stake" in the currency). Peercoin was the first cryptocurrency to
>   launch using proof-of-Stake. Other prominent implementations are found
>   in BitShares, Nxt, BlackCoin, NuShares/NuBits and Qora. Ethereum has
>   planned a hard fork transition from PoW to PoS consensus. Decred
>   hybridizes PoW with PoS and combines elements of both in an attempt to
>   garner the benefits of the two systems and create a more robust notion
>   of consensus.

Vitalik Buterin explains [here](https://blog.ethereum.org/2014/07/05/stake/) and [here](https://blog.ethereum.org/2014/11/25/proof-stake-learned-love-weak-subjectivity/) how Ethereum will be related to Proof of Stake.

Comment: anyone interested in the topic might listen to https://soundcloud.com/epicenterbitcoin/eb-105 it's absolutely not technical and explains very well how Casper deals with the Long-Range Attack and Nothing-at-Stake issue POS brings.